# How calculate pipe thickness from moment of inertia

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am creating a parametric spreadsheet to predict the behaviour of a sign post when subject to a specified wind speed for a uni assignment . Currently half way through creating the spreadsheet and one of the questions requires me to calculate a wall thickness of the pipe using the moment of inertia.. is this possible? if so how? please help guys all solutions are welcome :)!

Thanks

Comment: What information do you have about the pipe besides the moment of inertia?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the formula for moment of inertia for a circular ring (cross section of the pipe) but you would need to know the inside or outside diameter of the pipe to pin down its wall thickness. Assumes constant density of pipe material.